# ExpandableListView Adapter. get(int) on a null object

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Где я ошибаюсь? Сначала создал тестовый expandablelistview с адаптерами и т.д. но когда попытался подключить констанцию выдает ошибку.

```
    Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
esport.inyourlife.insport.ExpListAdapter.getChildView
```

Вот эту вот констанцию, я пытаюсь вывести список через модель данных

```
 package esport.inyourlife.insport.Consts;

public class Tournaments {
    public String id;
    public String TournName;
    public String TAdress;
    public String ToDate;
    public String ToTime;
    public String creator;
    public String sport;
    public String format;
    public String pole;
    public String level;
    public String minyear;
    public String maxteams;
    public String info;

    public Tournaments() {
    }

    public Tournaments(String id, String TName, String TAdress, String TDate, String TTime,
                       String creator, String format, String level, String minyear, String maxteams,
                       String info, String pole, String sport) {
        this.id = id;
        this.TournName = TName;
        this.TAdress = TAdress;
        this.ToDate = TDate;
        this.ToTime = TTime;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.format = format;
        this.level = level;
        this.minyear = minyear;
        this.maxteams = maxteams;
        this.info = info;
        this.pole = pole;
        this.sport = sport;
    }
}
```

Вот код самого адаптера

```js
package esport.inyourlife.insport;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import esport.inyourlife.insport.Consts.Tournaments;

public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<List<Tournaments>> mGroups;
    private Context mContext;

    public ExpListAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<List<Tournaments>> groups){
        mContext = context;
        mGroups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
        }

        if (isExpanded){
            //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group раскрыта
        }
        else{
            //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group скрыта
        }

        TextView textGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
        if (groupPosition==0){
            textGroup.setText("Football");
        } else if (groupPosition==1){
            textGroup.setText("Basketball");
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }

        TextView textChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textChild);
        textChild.setText((mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)).ToDate);



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

и код где я ее применяю если нужна

```js
 ArrayList<List<Tournaments>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> listDatas = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Tournaments> children2 = new ArrayList<>();
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            reference.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("Tournaments").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (listDatas.size() > 0) {
                        listDatas.clear();
                    }
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Tournaments getTurn = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                        if (getTurn != null) {
                            listTemp.add(getTurn);
                            /*listDatas.add(getTurn.TournName + ", " + getTurn.sport + ", " + getTurn.format +
                                    ", " + getTurn.TAdress + ", " + getTurn.ToDate + "." + getTurn.ToTime +
                                    ", " + getTurn.minyear);*/
                        }                }            }@Override public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
            });
            groups.add(listTemp);

            groups.add(children2);
            //Создаем адаптер и передаем context и список с данными
            ExpListAdapter adapter = new ExpListAdapter(getActivity(), groups);
            turnirs.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: у вас количество getGroupCount() getChildrenCount совпадает, что не должно быть

Comment: @Style-7 , Да, спасибо за подсказку, исправил. Я вообще не понимаю как эти адаптеры работают, я еле как написал для обычных списков, а тут еще и какие то позиции... вот кстати исходник откуда я переписал https://habr.com/ru/post/147546/

Comment: @Style-7, можешь подсказать как это доставать из firebase в класс, а потом в раскрывающийся список или накидать примеров для моих требований?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такс я нашел проблему. Спасибо @Style-7 за подсказку по дополнительной проблеме.
Проблема заключалось в том что я вводил данные в listTemp хотя надо было в listDatas. Просто нужен был свежий взгяд или что то вроде. А еще я поменял типы данных, на ArrayList(ArrayList). Я часто встречал нерешенные темы тут и было трудно найти решение поэтому если вам надо вывести данные из firebase в expendableListView то вот решение:

```js
ExpandableListView turnirs = (ExpandableListView)root.findViewById(R.id.expListView);
            //Создаем набор данных для адаптера
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Tournaments>> groups = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Tournaments>>();
            ArrayList<Tournaments> listDatas = new ArrayList<Tournaments>();
            ArrayList<Tournaments> children2 = new ArrayList<>();
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            reference.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("Tournaments").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (listDatas.size() > 0) {
                        listDatas.clear();
                    }
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Tournaments getTurn = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                        if (getTurn != null) {
                            listDatas.add(getTurn);
                            /*listDatas.add(getTurn.TournName + ", " + getTurn.sport + ", " + getTurn.format +
                                    ", " + getTurn.TAdress + ", " + getTurn.ToDate + "." + getTurn.ToTime +
                                    ", " + getTurn.minyear);*/
                        }                }            }@Override public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
            });
            groups.add(listDatas);

            groups.add(listDatas);
            //Создаем адаптер и передаем context и список с данными
            ExpListAdapter adapter = new ExpListAdapter(getActivity(), groups);
            turnirs.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Сначала вызываем все данные, а потом если нужно передаем его в свой адаптер:

```js
package esport.inyourlife.insport;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.type.DateTime;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import esport.inyourlife.insport.Consts.Tournaments;

import static android.media.CamcorderProfile.get;

public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Tournaments>> mGroups;
    private Context mContext;

    public ExpListAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<Tournaments>> groups){
        mContext = context;
        mGroups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
        }

        if (isExpanded){
            //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group раскрыта
        }
        else{
            //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group скрыта
        }
        TextView textGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
        if (groupPosition==0){
            textGroup.setText("Football");
        } else if (groupPosition==1){
            textGroup.setText("Basketball");
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }
        Tournaments tournaments = mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
        TextView textChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textChild);
        textChild.setText(tournaments.ToDate);
        TextView league = convertView.findViewById(R.id.league);
        league.setText(tournaments.format);
        TextView startto = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tostart);
        startto.setText(tournaments.ToDate);



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Не забудьте поменять/добавить свою разметку и все готово)